# How to replace a character with null

Tags: perl

I have one string
`"8.53"` I want my resulting string `"853"`
I have tried 
the following code

```
tr|.||;
```

but its not replacing its giving `8.53` only . 
I have tried another way using

```
tr|.|NULL|;
```

but its giving `8N53` can anyone please suggest me how to use tr to replace a character with NULL.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean remove the character? You probably don't want a null character there...

Comment: Yes I want to remove the . character .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't want `tr` because that transliterates characters from the 1st list with the corresponding character in the 2nd list (which was `N` in your example since that was the first character). You'll want the substitution operator.

```
my $var = "8.53";
$var =~ s/\.//;
print $var;
```

Add the `g` flag if there are multiple instances you want to replace (`s/\.//g`).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply.Its giving me the desired result.

Comment: Or, as ikegami demonstrates below, you *do* want `tr` - you just need to give it the correct option (`/d`) :-)

Answer (score 16):

You need to specify the `d` modifier to delete chars with no corresponding char:

```
tr/.//d;
```

Or you could use the (slower but more familiar) substitution operator:

```
s/\.//g;
```